# Knockout js and Raven DB

Tags: c#, knockout.js, ravendb

I'm currently developing an application based on no-sql (using raven db). The core aspect of this application is a tree-like data structure with many nodes, subnodes and so on.

Currently, each node or subnode is represented by a c# object. A parent-child relationship is made with a collection of subnodes on the parent node, a forward-only relationship.

The whole thing is handled by ad hoc forms, in an Mvc application, with proper GETs and POSTs for each data type. The whole graph is stored as JSON on Raven DB.

Now the goal is to modify the UI part using knockoutjs. Since KO works with json data structures as well, I was wondering if there is a way to make the ravendb json structure "knockout compatible", meaning I can directly use it without having to make a KO specific structure (to implement observables, etc) and then create a mapping between the two.

A sample of the object graph:

```
public class NodeA
{
public string Name {get;set;}
public List<SubNode> Childs {get;set;}
}

public class SubNode
{
public string Name {get;set;}
public bool SomeBool {get;set;}
}

public class NodeB
{
public string Name {get;set;}
public int SomeInt {get;set;}
}

public class GraphToStore
{
public List<NodeA> NodeAList {get;set;}
public List<NodeB> NodeBList {get;set;}
}
```

The read/write part would still be handled server side, with ajax calls after stuff gets updated on the UI. Validation would be server-side and returned to the client via ajax calls too. My problem is as I said making the ravendb json work with knockoutjs, otherwise I have to reconstruct the whole thing and map it, and the graph is huge (50+ classes).

Comment: I have no experiencing with Raven DB, but if the JSON generated by it looks similar like the return of NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object), then it would be no problem I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Knockout-mapping-plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).  It will "automagically" generate the knockout compatible viewmodel with one call.

You would do something like

```
var viewModel.myRavenDbData = ko.mapping.fromJSON(json data variable);
var unwrappedData = viewModel.myRavenDbData(); // need only if viewModel.myRavenDbData is an observable
```

After you have this working, breakpoint after the call to mapping and explore the data structure.  Generally, it will look like your data structure with ko.observables for the actual values.  All the nodes needed for navigation will be normal javascript objects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the [Knockouts Mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) capabilities and create ViewModels directly from the model objects. But, I have two points:

1) I think that the fact that the objects are stored in RavenDB does not metter. Your MVC applications retrieves the objects from RavenDB - so they are deserialized from JSON and than they are served to your JS page via REST interface, so they are serialized again into JSON. So you are not working directly with the RavenDB's JSON structure, it is a standard  CLR object serialized to JSON.

If you want to work directly with Raven, you have to plug your application directly to raven's interface - and that is not a good idea (but of course in the metter of performance it should work great).

2) I don't think that it is good idea to use your model objects as ViewModels, only by using the knockout mapping plugin.

Soon you will need to add some logic to the view model. Either for computing values to be showed in the view, or adding some action logic (save/edit...etc).

For the first case, you can define your viewmodels on the server side and use the mapping plugin.

For the later, you will have to write the view models in javascript anyway. I would recomend start writing the viewmodels in javascript directly.

It works the best for me.